# How to properly setup adb/PATH for intellij

Tags: intellij-idea, adb

I am using intellij for developing flutter apps on fedora linux.

I install the Android SDK via intellij to `~/development/Android/Sdk`.

In my `.bashrc` I setup my PATH so that I can use adb and other tools from the Android SDK when I am in the terminal.

But for intellij these tools are not known (intellij does not execute my `.bashrc` before starting) and intellij cannot find adb.

The effect is, that intellij cannot find my Android Emulator.

I can fix this by making a symlink:

`~/development/Android/Sdk/platform-tools/adb -> /usr/local/bin/adb`

But this feels like a hack.

- Can I in some other way tell intellij where adb is located?
- Can I configure intellij in some way, so that its PATH Variable is also extended and it can find adb at the correct place?

Comment: Does it work from the OS terminal? Have you restarted the IDE after modifying the `.bashrc`?

Comment: @Andrey If I start idea from the command line it works, which makes sense because PATH is set in that environment. Yes, I have restarted idea.

Comment: What shell do you use and how do you load `.bashrc` file for shell? You can check if this file is read by IDE terminal by echo-ing something from it and opening IDE terminal/ It works for me when I use `source <path to bashrc>` command in my `~/.bash-profile` file.

Comment: I use the bash sell, and .bashrc is just loaded. It is loaded by the IDE terminal, but that does not help. Intellij still cannot find my android emulator.

Comment: Then I do not understand the problem from your description. What exactly does not work in IDE?

Comment: That the IDE itself is able to detect adb. Its nice, that I can use adb in the terminal. But I want to use the adb features of the ide. For example in intellij, there is a dropdown showing me the devices detected by adb so that I can install my current project on it.

Comment: How do you want to use adb in IDE when it does not work? Do you use it in Android project? Do you have Android SDK set for this project (in Settings (Preferences on macOS) |  | Appearance & Behavior | System Settings | **Android SDK** and Settings (Preferences on macOS) | Other Settings | **Android Project Structure**)?

Comment: Adb works. I have the Android SDK installed via intellij. The ADV Device Manager in Intellij also works. I can created devices and start the emularor. Then the command line I can also see the emulator (using adb devices). But the dropdown, within intellij where one chooses the device to deploy to, shows "<no devices>" and I cannot deploy or debug from intellij.

Comment: `But the dropdown, within intellij where one chooses the device to deploy to, shows "<no devices>"` Please include the screenshot in a full IDE window. What Tools | Android | AVM Manager shows? Have you created the Run/Debug Configuration in IDE? Note that Run Configuration must exist: https://monosnap.com/file/HiqzCxQKQ6h3dgInHqOsfkaSsyUzM2